# ContiPerf html report

Tags: java, load-testing, contiperf

I am running contiperf with `mvn test` and I get a report in the folder "contiperf -report", but I do not see any images/pictures either in the report or in the folder.

Does anybody have the same problem and know how to solve it? Does the computer needs to be online to make this work? I am not online when executing my contiperf tests.

Cheers
Magnus

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you **must** be online because charts are generated with [Google chart API](https://github.com/lucaspouzac/contiperf/blob/19c7c64f1abba748e7bf1550699d6590e929ee79/src/main/java/org/databene/contiperf/report/GoogleLatencyRenderer.java#L61). Here an example of charts :

```
<img src='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lxy&chs=320x240&chd=t:47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54|0,80,75,1,0,0,0,0&chxt=x&chxr=0,0,54&chds=0,54,0,100&chf=c,lg,0,FFFFFF,0,FFFF88,1&chm=B,FFE69B,0,0,0|Aavg,666666,0,1,15|Amed,666666,0,1,15|A90%,666666,0,2,15' width='320', height='240'/
```

Answer (score 0):

it generates beautiful reports. what version you are using? the only problem i find is sometimes i am getting pergen space error but nothing to do with contiperf.

I don't think you need to be online. it is like junit test reports and running off your maven test